# Problem with TabActivity on FullScreen when restoring from pause

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget

I got an issue with a TabActivity for which I've found no solution yet.
The thing is, when I press 'home' and then reopening the app (onRestart called)
the whole layout moves downwards even though it's set on full screen. I tried settings
the layout params to FULL_SCREEN inside onRestart but had no luck with that.
Has any of you experienced something similar using TabActivity on Full Screen?
I fear this is a platform bug, hope there's a fix though

Comment: did you find any solution for this issue? i am also facing the same problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update the TabActivity onResume with the following.

```
 Handler mHandler = new Handler();

 protected void onResume() {
   super.onResume();
   mHandler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
      public void run() {
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                             WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
      }
   }, 500);    
 }
```

I hope this works.

Comment: +1. It sounds cool. Its working fine for me. Thanks a lot Vijay.